# Persist dataframe ignores StorageLevel

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with spark SQL dataframes and am having an issue with persisting to speed up later computations.  Specifically, when calling `persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)` and then subsequently checking in the Spark UI's 'Storage' tab I'm able to see the RDDs being cached but the storage level always shows `Memory Deserialized 1x Replicated` and the "Size on Disk" column shows 0.0 B for all RDDs.

I've also tried `MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER` but get the same results.  I'm curious if anyone has seen this or if I'm doing something incorrectly here.  Reviewing the spark docs, shows that calling either `cache()` or `persist()` on a dataframe defaults to a storage level of `MEMORY_AND_DISK` and using the `cacheTable` method in SQLContext states that it `Caches the specified table in-memory.`

For some additional information, a general skeleton of my program's flow is:

```
// Here computeHeavyMethod is some code that returns a DataFrame
val tableData = computeHeavyMethod().persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
tableData.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json(outputLocation)
tableData.createOrReplaceTempView(tableName)

spark.sql("Some sql statement that uses the table created above")
```

Comment: Move this line to the end and try. tableData.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).json(outputLocation)

Comment: Same experience here.  There are some real bizarre and unintuitive things going on with persist().  For example a persisted DF ("myDF") will run a count() really fast... but if you then create a view on it (createOrReplaceTempView) and run count() on "myDF" once again it becomes slow - retrieving data from storage as if the persist wasn't called.  Its like the createOrReplaceTempView operation is not only messing with the SQL -related alias but is also negatively impacting the original DF and subverting the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) says:

> MEMORY_AND_DISK
>
> Store RDD as deserialized Java objects in the JVM. If the RDD does not
>   fit in memory, store the partitions that don't fit on disk, and read
>   them from there when they're needed.

So disk storage is only used if you running out of (storage) memory

Comment: I had seen this and it makes sense, what was throwing me off was the "Storage Level" column which always showed `Memory Deserialized 1x Replicated`; even though the dataframe hadn't spilled to disk I'd expected that to show Memory and Disk or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

With Spark 2.2.0 at least, it looks like "disk" is only shown when the RDD is completely spilled to disk:

```
StorageLevel: StorageLevel(disk, 1 replicas); CachedPartitions: 36; 
TotalPartitions: 36; MemorySize: 0.0 B; DiskSize: 3.3 GB
```

For a partially spilled RDD, the StorageLevel is shown as "memory":

```
StorageLevel: StorageLevel(memory, deserialized, 1 replicas); 
CachedPartitions: 36; TotalPartitions: 36; MemorySize: 3.4 GB; DiskSize: 1158.0 MB
```